# C++ returning a vector and displaying it properly

Tags: c++, vector

I am attempting to create a function that returns a `vector` as an answer, ie [1,3]. I am confused about the process of manipulating that information once the function has been called. Should I set it equal to a new `vector`? How would I then display the contents of this new `vector`? Here is my code for reference. When I attempt to set the function call to a new `vector` and display it, I get an out of bounds error.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> twoNumberSum(vector<int> array, int targetSum);

int main()
{
  int tSum = 10;
  vector<int> test{3,5,-4,8,11,1,-1,6};

  twoNumberSum(test,tSum);
}

//O^2 complexity
//Two number Sum
vector<int> twoNumberSum(vector<int> array, int targetSum)
{
  for (int i=0; i<array.size() -1; i++)
  {
    int firstNum = array[i];
    for(int j=i+1;i<array.size();i++)
    {
      int secondNum = array[j];
      if(firstNum + secondNum == targetSum)
      {
        return vector<int>{firstNum,secondNum};
      }
    }
  }
  return {};
}
```

Comment: Your inner loop `for` statement references the wrong variable in two of the three expressions.

Comment: Your code has the time complexity of O(n^2) because you have 2 nested ```for``` loops.  However, if you had used 1 ```for``` loop and 1  ```unordered_map```, then the time complexity would have been O(n).

Comment: FYI --  If you're attempting to answer this question, and it comes from one of those "competitive coding" website, if the number of numbers is very large, your solution will more than likely result in a "time out error".   This is even after you fix the issue with the vectors.  If the vector consisted of 1,000 numbers, you are looping a million times.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 How would that reduce the complexity? Looking up something from an `unordered_map` is O(N), right?

Comment: As for the question, why have you omitted the code where you try to display it, especially if the error is there? Have you used a debugger so far? Have you printed out the vectors size? If you display two numbers but the `return {};` happened, for instance, it would access out of bounds.

Comment: @Aziuth, The search operation (i.e. looking for) an item in the ```unordered_map``` has the time complexity of O(1).  So, using an ```unordered_map```  would be faster.  You can search for any answer on ```unordered_map``` to get more info about it.

Answer (score 0):

To print vector, you could use something like this:

```
void printVector(vector<int> v) {
    cout << "{";
    for(int item : v) {
        cout << item << ", ";
    }
    cout << "}";
}
```

And use it as in a main function: `print_vector(twoNumberSum(test, tSum));`

Now, bug.

> for(int j=i+1;**i**<array.size();**i**++)

You increase and check the value of variable **i**, but you need to use **j** there.
That will be correct: `for(int j=i+1;j<array.size();j++)`

The program works correctly and prints the result of function to the console:

```
void print_vector(vector<int> v);
vector<int> twoNumberSum(vector<int> array, int targetSum);
int main()
{
  int tSum = 10;
  vector<int> test{3,5,-4,8,11,1,-1,6};

  print_vector(twoNumberSum(test, tSum));
}


vector<int> twoNumberSum(vector<int> array, int targetSum)
{
  for (int i=0; i<array.size() -1; i++)
  {
    int firstNum = array[i];
    for(int j=i+1;j<array.size();j++)
    {
      int secondNum = array[j];
      if(firstNum + secondNum == targetSum)
      {
        return vector<int>{firstNum,secondNum};
      }
   }
  }
  return {};
}

void print_vector(vector<int> v) {
    cout << "{";
    for(int item : v) {
        cout << item << ", ";
    }
    cout << "}";
}
```

Comment: Why minus one? The code already contains a < instead of a <=. Right now, your code ignores the last entry.

Comment: pass vector by const reference to avoid extra copies.

Comment: Aziuth is right. This is my fault. I fixed the answer